# Delete Rows older than 1 year in Google Sheets (Large Data Set)

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

I have a fairly large dataset containing about 40,000 rows (New rows added daily). I want to run a script daily that deletes rows that are older than 1 year.

I have been using this one that has worked ok, but as my dataset gets larger it times out and fails to run.

here is what I have been using:

```
    function deleteFIVEoh() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("theFIVEoh");
    var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
    var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array

    var currentDate = new Date();//today
    var yearOld = Date.now() + -365*24*3600*1000; 
    for (i=lastrow;i>=3;i--) {
    var tempDate = values[i-1][4];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col12 =. 
    [11]
    if ((tempDate!="") && (tempDate <= (yearOld)))
    {
    sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
    }
    }
```

The data on my sheet is always sorted in ascending order (oldest entries at the top). Is there any way I can get this to work faster? Maybe by looking at the first 500 rows only?

Thanks in advance!
-wes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sheet is sorted in ascending order, it is much better to start at the top, count the number of rows that satisfy your condition, then use a single `deleteRows()` method.

```
function deleteFIVEoh() {
    const MS_IN_ONE_YEAR = 365*24*3600*1000;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("theFIVEoh");
    var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array
  
    var currentDate = new Date();//today
    var yearOld = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - MS_IN_ONE_YEAR);

    for (i = 0; values[i][4] < yearOld; i++) {}
    sheet.deleteRows(1,i);
}
```

A single call is much faster than a looped API call, and there are less iterations in this code as well as it does not need to go through the entire sheet.

Sample before execution:

[image]

Sample after execution:

[image]

Comment: It appears that this will simply delete a number of rows regardless if it was older than a year or not.

Comment: It was indicated that the sheet is always in ascending order (oldest on top). So it will delete the oldest rows first, starting from row 1.

Comment: I am getting "these rows are out of bounds"  on line12.

Comment: I have a header row so if i set line 12 to be:

        sheet.deleteRows(2,500);

It just deletes rows 2 - 500 regardless of date.